# Issues with Declaring a C++ Priority Queue using a custom Comparator

Tags: c++, compare, priority-queue

I have been trying to implement a Priority queue consisting of a custom data type and a custom comparator but when I try to compile I get this error. I have tried multiple declarations but they all yield this error.

```
priority_queue<myData, vector<myData>, myComp> myPQ;

priority_queue<myData, vector<myData>, myComp> myPQ(compVariable);
```

I also am trying to create a vector of these priority queues after creating them.

```
   /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_function.h: In instantiation of ‘bool std::less<_Tp>::operator()(const _Tp&, const _Tp&) const [with _Tp = Order]’:
/usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_heap.h:183:47:   required from ‘void std::__push_heap(_RandomAccessIterator, _Distance, _Distance, _Tp, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Order*, std::vector<Order, std::allocator<Order> > >; _Distance = long int; _Tp = Order; _Compare = std::less<Order>]’
/usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_heap.h:222:58:   required from ‘void std::push_heap(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Order*, std::vector<Order, std::allocator<Order> > >; _Compare = std::less<Order>]’
/usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_queue.h:499:41:   required from ‘void std::priority_queue<_Tp, _Sequence, _Compare>::push(const value_type&) [with _Tp = Order; _Sequence = std::vector<Order, std::allocator<Order> >; _Compare = std::less<Order>; std::priority_queue<_Tp, _Sequence, _Compare>::value_type = Order]’
Market.cpp:144:32:   required from here
/usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_function.h:235:20: error: no match for ‘operator<’ (operand types are ‘const Order’ and ‘const Order’)
       { return __x < __y; }
                    ^
/usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_function.h:235:20: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_algobase.h:64:0,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/ios:40,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/iostream:39,
                 from Market.cpp:1:
/usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_pair.h:220:5: note: template<class _T1, class _T2> constexpr bool std::operator<(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&, const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&)
     operator<(const pair<_T1, _T2>& __x, const pair<_T1, _T2>& __y)
     ^
/usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_pair.h:220:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/string:48:0,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/ios:42,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/iostream:39,
                 from Market.cpp:1:
/usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_function.h:235:20: note:   ‘const Order’ is not derived from ‘const std::pair<_T1, _T2>’
       { return __x < __y; }
                    ^
In file included from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_algobase.h:67:0,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/ios:40,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/iostream:39,
                 from Market.cpp:1:
/usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_iterator.h:297:5: note: template<class _Iterator> bool std::operator<(const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&, const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&)
     operator<(const reverse_iterator<_Iterator>& __x,
     ^
/usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_iterator.h:297:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/string:48:0,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/ios:42,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/iostream:39,
                 from Market.cpp:1:
/usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_function.h:235:20: note:   ‘const Order’ is not derived from ‘const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>’
       { return __x < __y; }
                    ^
In file included from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_algobase.h:67:0,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/ios:40,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/iostream:39,
                 from Market.cpp:1:
/usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_iterator.h:347:5: note: template<class _IteratorL, class _IteratorR> bool std::operator<(const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&, const std::reverse_iterator<_IteratorR>&)
     operator<(const reverse_iterator<_IteratorL>& __x,
     ^
/usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_iterator.h:347:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/string:48:0,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/ios:42,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/iostream:39,
                 from Market.cpp:1:
/usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_function.h:235:20: note:   ‘const Order’ is not derived from ‘const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>’
       { return __x < __y; }
                    ^
In file included from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_algobase.h:67:0,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/ios:40,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/iostream:39,
                 from Market.cpp:1:
/usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_iterator.h:1055:5: note: template<class _IteratorL, class _IteratorR> bool std::operator<(const std::move_iterator<_Iterator>&, const std::move_iterator<_IteratorR>&)
     operator<(const move_iterator<_IteratorL>& __x,
     ^
/usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_iterator.h:1055:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/string:48:0,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/ios:42,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/iostream:39,
                 from Market.cpp:1:
/usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_function.h:235:20: note:   ‘const Order’ is not derived from ‘const std::move_iterator<_Iterator>’
       { return __x < __y; }
                    ^
In file included from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_algobase.h:67:0,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/ios:40,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/iostream:39,
                 from Market.cpp:1:
/usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_iterator.h:1061:5: note: template<class _Iterator> bool std::operator<(const std::move_iterator<_Iterator>&, const std::move_iterator<_Iterator>&)
     operator<(const move_iterator<_Iterator>& __x,
     ^
/usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_iterator.h:1061:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/string:48:0,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/ios:42,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/iostream:39,
                 from Market.cpp:1:
/usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_function.h:235:20: note:   ‘const Order’ is not derived from ‘const std::move_iterator<_Iterator>’
       { return __x < __y; }
                    ^
In file included from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/string:52:0,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/ios:42,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/iostream:39,
                 from Market.cpp:1:
/usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/basic_string.h:2569:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> bool std::operator<(const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
     operator<(const basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& __lhs,
     ^
/usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/basic_string.h:2569:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/string:48:0,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/ios:42,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/iostream:39,
                 from Market.cpp:1:
/usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_function.h:235:20: note:   ‘const Order’ is not derived from ‘const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>’
       { return __x < __y; }
                    ^
In file included from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/string:52:0,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/ios:42,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/iostream:39,
                 from Market.cpp:1:
/usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/basic_string.h:2581:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> bool std::operator<(const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, const _CharT*)
     operator<(const basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& __lhs,
     ^
/usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/basic_string.h:2581:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/string:48:0,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/ios:42,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/iostream:39,
                 from Market.cpp:1:
/usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_function.h:235:20: note:   ‘const Order’ is not derived from ‘const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>’
       { return __x < __y; }
                    ^
In file included from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/string:52:0,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/ios:42,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/iostream:39,
                 from Market.cpp:1:
/usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/basic_string.h:2593:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> bool std::operator<(const _CharT*, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
     operator<(const _CharT* __lhs,
     ^
/usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/basic_string.h:2593:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/string:48:0,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/ios:42,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/iostream:39,
                 from Market.cpp:1:
/usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_function.h:235:20: note:   mismatched types ‘const _CharT*’ and ‘Order’
       { return __x < __y; }
                    ^
In file included from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/vector:64:0,
                 from P2.h:4,
                 from Market.cpp:3:
/usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_vector.h:1420:5: note: template<class _Tp, class _Alloc> bool std::operator<(const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&, const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&)
     operator<(const vector<_Tp, _Alloc>& __x, const vector<_Tp, _Alloc>& __y)
     ^
/usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_vector.h:1420:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/string:48:0,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/ios:42,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/iostream:39,
                 from Market.cpp:1:
/usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_function.h:235:20: note:   ‘const Order’ is not derived from ‘const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>’
       { return __x < __y; }
                    ^
In file included from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/deque:64:0,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/queue:60,
                 from Market.cpp:6:
/usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_deque.h:273:5: note: template<class _Tp, class _Ref, class _Ptr> bool std::operator<(const std::_Deque_iterator<_Tp, _Ref, _Ptr>&, const std::_Deque_iterator<_Tp, _Ref, _Ptr>&)
     operator<(const _Deque_iterator<_Tp, _Ref, _Ptr>& __x,
     ^
/usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_deque.h:273:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/string:48:0,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/ios:42,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/iostream:39,
                 from Market.cpp:1:
/usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_function.h:235:20: note:   ‘const Order’ is not derived from ‘const std::_Deque_iterator<_Tp, _Ref, _Ptr>’
       { return __x < __y; }
                    ^
In file included from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/deque:64:0,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/queue:60,
                 from Market.cpp:6:
/usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_deque.h:281:5: note: template<class _Tp, class _RefL, class _PtrL, class _RefR, class _PtrR> bool std::operator<(const std::_Deque_iterator<_Tp, _Ref, _Ptr>&, const std::_Deque_iterator<_Tp, _RefR, _PtrR>&)
     operator<(const _Deque_iterator<_Tp, _RefL, _PtrL>& __x,
     ^
/usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_deque.h:281:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/string:48:0,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/ios:42,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/iostream:39,
                 from Market.cpp:1:
/usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_function.h:235:20: note:   ‘const Order’ is not derived from ‘const std::_Deque_iterator<_Tp, _Ref, _Ptr>’
       { return __x < __y; }
                    ^
In file included from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/deque:64:0,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/queue:60,
                 from Market.cpp:6:
/usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_deque.h:1975:5: note: template<class _Tp, class _Alloc> bool std::operator<(const std::deque<_Tp, _Alloc>&, const std::deque<_Tp, _Alloc>&)
     operator<(const deque<_Tp, _Alloc>& __x,
     ^
/usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_deque.h:1975:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/string:48:0,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/ios:42,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/iostream:39,
                 from Market.cpp:1:
/usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_function.h:235:20: note:   ‘const Order’ is not derived from ‘const std::deque<_Tp, _Alloc>’
       { return __x < __y; }
                    ^
In file included from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/queue:64:0,
                 from Market.cpp:6:
/usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_queue.h:286:5: note: template<class _Tp, class _Seq> bool std::operator<(const std::queue<_Tp, _Seq>&, const std::queue<_Tp, _Seq>&)
     operator<(const queue<_Tp, _Seq>& __x, const queue<_Tp, _Seq>& __y)
     ^
/usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_queue.h:286:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/string:48:0,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/ios:42,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/iostream:39,
                 from Market.cpp:1:
/usr/um/gcc-4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_function.h:235:20: note:   ‘const Order’ is not derived from ‘const std::queue<_Tp, _Seq>’
       { return __x < __y; }
```

Here is an example of what is causing the error:

```
class myData {
public:
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;
};

class myComp {
public:
    bool operator()(myData& d1, myData& d2) {
        if(d1.a == d2.a) {
            return d2.b < d2.c;
        }
        else {
            return d1.a < d2.a;
        }
    }
};

priority_queue<myData, vector<myData>, myComp> myPQ;

vector<priority_queue<myData, vector<myData>, myComp> > vec_PQ(n, myPQ);
```

Comment: Are you sure that your "Order" class has "<" operator overloaded?

Comment: The first error looks like you used the type `priority_queue<Order, std::vector<Order>>` without any custom comparator. Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can actually compile.

Comment: @sithereal, The point of using a custom comparator is that it doesn't need one.

Comment: Sorry, I meant 'Are you sure that your "Order" class has "()" operator overloaded?'

Comment: `void std::priority_queue<_Tp, _Sequence, _Compare>::push(const value_type&) [with _Tp = Order; _Sequence = std::vector<Order, std::allocator<Order> >; _Compare = std::less<Order>; std::priority_queue<_Tp, _Sequence, _Compare>::value_type = Order]`...yes, definitely looks like a vanilla `priority_queue<Order>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare

> The concept **Compare** is a set of requirements expected by some of the standard library facilities from the user-provided function object types.
>
> The return value of the function call operation applied to an object of type Compare, when contextually converted to `bool`, yields `true` if the first argument of the call appears before the second in the *strict weak ordering relation* induced by this Compare type, and `false` otherwise.
>
> As with any BinaryPredicate, evaluation of that expression is not allowed to call non-const member functions of the dereferenced iterators.

The arguments to `myComp::operator()` should be `const&`.

```
bool myComp::operator()(myData const& d1, myData const& d2) {
```

As indicated by @T.C. in a comment, the function itself should be a const member function but that is strictly not necessary in this case.

Comment: And the `operator()` itself should be `const`. But that's not the point.